# Use input of one method as input to another method

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have attached the verify.blade.php file and the edited code of controller as well as the route file, i.e. web.php related to these views. Kindly help me out with accessing the data of the patient who's the first name I enter in verification view. When I enter the name of this patient, it should fetch only the data of that patient.  In my case first name as input to where clause. Whatever I enter in verify view first name should be taken as input to report method.

In my controller I'm currently using firstname, contact and bloodgroup of the patient to verify the patient. Once the data entered matches the data stored in database the report method executes and returns the report table. This report table should be displayed based on the firstname i entered in the verify view.

This is my Controller:

```
    public function fetch(Request $req)
    {
        $firstname = $req->input('firstname');
        $contact=$req->input('contact');
        $bloodgroup=$req->input('bloodgroup');
        $verify= DB::select('select id from patient_details where firstname=? and contact=? and bloodgroup=?',[$firstname,$contact,$bloodgroup]);
        if(count($verify))
        {
            return redirect('report');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed";
        }
    }
    public function report()
    {
        
        $data = DB::table('patient_details')->where('patient_details.firstname','=',$firstname)
        
        ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')
        ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
        ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
        ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')       
        
        ->get();
        
        return view('report',compact('data'));
    }
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('/verify', function () {
    return view('/verify');
});
Route::post('verify/fetch', 'JoinController@report');
Route::get('/report','JoinController@report');
```

This is my veridy.blade.php

```
    <form action="{{url('/verify/fetch')}}" method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w">
                @CSRF 
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-32">
                        Personal Details
                    </span>
                    <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                        Username
                    </span>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Username is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                        Contact
                    </span>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Email is required">
                        <input  class="input100" type="text" name="contact" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                        Blood-Group
                    </span>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Email is required">
                        <input  class="input100" type="text" name="bloodgroup" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-48">
                        <div>
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center container-login100-form-btn">
                        <a class="login100-form-btn" >
                            <button type="submit" name="action"  class="login100-form-btn">
                                Verify
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    
                    </div>
                


                </form>
```

This is my report.blade.php

```
    <form >
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr  class="bg-danger text-light">
                <th>Patient First Name</th>
                <th>Patient Last Name</th>
                <th>Patient Address</th>
                <th>Patient Contact</th>
                <th>Patient BloodGroup</th>
                <th>Patient Date-Of-Birth</th>
                <th>Patient CNIC</th>
                <th>Patient Gender</th>
                <th>Patient Blood Pressure Reading</th>
                <th>Patient Temperature Reading</th>
                <th>Patient ECG Reading</th>
                <th>Patient Medical Record</th>
                <th>Payment Type</th>
                <th>Total Payment</th>
                <th>Remaining Payment</th>
            </tr>
            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data as $row)
            <tr  class="bg-secondary text-light">
            <td>{{$row->firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->contact}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->bloodgroup}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->dateofbirth}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->cnic}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->gender}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->bp}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->temp}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->ecg}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->prerecord}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->ptype}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->tpayment}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->rpayment}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand when a verify form is submitted and in the fetch method it is verified you want to show the report view.

If that is correct, you can try the below

```php
public function fetch(Request $req)
{
    $firstname = $req->input('firstname');
    $contact=$req->input('contact');
    $bloodgroup=$req->input('bloodgroup');

    $verify= DB::select('select id from patient_details where firstname=? and contact=? and bloodgroup=?',[$firstname,$contact,$bloodgroup]);

    if(count($verify))
    {
        return $this->report($req);
    }
    else
    {
       return response(['message' => 'Failed!'], 400);
    }
}


public function report(Request $request)
{
    $firstname = $request->input('firstname');
        
    $data = DB::table('patient_details')->where('patient_details.firstname','=',$firstname)
        
        ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id', '=', 'patient_details.id')
        ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
        ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
        ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')       
        
        ->get();
        
    return view('report',compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Sir, it says undefined variable req. I also changed req to request then It displays the table but the table is empty

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd($firstname, $data)` in the report function just before the return statement

Comment: null Illuminate\Support\Collection {#334 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: Which means the $request->input('firstname') is null. Thats because you have named the parameter in the fetch method as $req while passed $request in the report  `$this->report($request)` while it should be `$this->report($req)`. Have updated answer pls check and see it should work now. - let me know if otherwise

Comment: still the same null

Comment: Mean you still get null and empty collection when `dd($firstname, $data)` just before the return statement in report method - even after changing to `return $this->report($req)` in the fetch method?

Comment: Yes sir, im still getting a null returned in dd

Comment: What is the value of $firstname if you do a `dd($req->input('firstname')` in fetch method

Comment: sir how to do this dd($req->input('firstname'));

Comment: Just place `dd($req->input('firstname');` as the first statement in the fetch method and see what you get

Comment: sir when i put dd($req->input('firstname'); i shows the record

Comment: doesnt take me to dd view it shows the record in the table

Comment: `dd($req->input('firstname');` output a single string value or null in fetch method. If you are getting null then check the blade view with form whether you have an input with firstname or not. The verify.blade.php in your question doesn't have any input field with name="firstname"

Comment: sir i corrected ht name = usernme to name = firstname earlier

Comment: now i see the record for which I enter the first name in verify view

Comment: Place `dd($req->input('firstname');` as the first line in the fetch method & submit the form again - if it shows the value which you typed for firstname in the form, then comment out the dd line in fetch and resubmit the form it should work. By the way `->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')` should be `->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id', '=', 'patient_details.id')`

Comment: yes sir it is working fine now. thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

In your specific situation I would use sessions. I would do

```
    public function fetch(Request $req)
    {
        $firstname = $req->input('firstname');
        $contact=$req->input('contact');
        $bloodgroup=$req->input('bloodgroup');
        $verify= DB::select('select id from patient_details where firstname=? and contact=? and bloodgroup=?',[$firstname,$contact,$bloodgroup]);
        if(count($verify))
        {
            session()->put('current_report_name', $firstname);
            return redirect('report');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed";
        }
    }
    public function report()
    {
        $firstname = session()->get('current_report_name');
        $data = DB::table('patient_details')->where('patient_details.firstname','=',$firstname)
        
        ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')
        ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
        ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
        ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')       
        
        ->get();
        
        return view('report',compact('data'));
    }
```

However you can fetch and display data from the same single route, having it separate like this peculiar but in your specific use case I would say it would be ok. It just means if a user fetches a different user and goes back to a previous open tab and refreshes, the old tab will become the latest fetched user

Comment: Sir it doesnt display anything in the table. Table view is being shown but no data is being fetched.

Comment: Sorry ignore the last part where I had the routes partly clipped. You should use your routes

Comment: Sir, I kept the routes same

Comment: Also it looks like your veridy.blade.php does not have the correct inputs for your fetch (eg you have username instead of firstname)

Comment: You may get no result because you have so many joins. A join will only show results if there are other results on those tables too. Mayne you want a left join

Comment: Yes sir i just noticed i fixed that and it is still showing null in dd

Comment: Try some tests where you remove the joins and see if you get a result on the report function of the controller. Also check that $firstname is not empty with echo or dd

Comment: sir if i use left join i do not get results on my report I have tried this several times earlier. only when I sed join at all places all the results were displayed

Comment: Join means only find the main table (patient details) if all other tables you join exist. Left join means get it even if the joins don't exits.

Comment: If you do debugging at each step with dd() to see exactly at what point the info is no longer displaying you will find the root cause

Comment: Okay sir im trying this

Comment: Sir i changed the 2 join at bottom to left join and it is showing me the result for all tables. So there is no issue in join?